# Getting TikTok Followers Usernames

Tags: javascript, api, curl, sdk, tiktok

Can anyone point me to a solution on how to get the usernames of all my followers from TikTok? Maybe an SDK or an API solution? I don't care on what language it's written, but I wouldn't mind if it could be JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiktok-api It has a method .listFollowers(params) which could be your solution

Answer (score 1):

There is an [unofficial TikTok API](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api) for Python if you are comfortable with using that. And there is a [Node.js API](https://github.com/tikstock/tiktok-app-api) I found, too.